# What is Germany's national sport or sports?

Tags: rules, trivia

Does Germany have any national sport or sports, and if so, what are they?

Germany is not mentioned in the [English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_sport) or [German](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nationalsport) language Wikipedia articles on national sports, but doesn't explicitly state that they don't have a national sport either.

Comment: They like soccer

Answer (score 1):

I found "The national sport of Germany is football" at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sport_in_Germany

My personal experience visiting my inlaws in a village in northern Germany with my two boys is that in addition, soccer is a big deal in everyday life, in addition to the pro teams, the World Cup, etc.

Answer (score -2):

Soccer is the national sport in Germany.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for this answer?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sport_in_Germany  -   Football in Germany is (like in most European countries) the number one attended and practiced sport. Besides the national league, the Euro cup and the FIFA World Cup has much attention among its population.

Comment: To quote from the Wikipedia [National sport](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_sport) article: "[National sports] do not have to be necessarily the most played or most followed, which would be either association football or basketball in all but a few countries, but are widely considered to be important to the country or significant for its culture."